# sed emulate "tr | grep"

Tags: bash, sed, grep

Given the following file

```
$ cat a.txt
FOO='hhh';BAR='eee';BAZ='ooo'
```

I can easily parse out one item with `tr` and `grep`

```
$ tr ';' '\n' < a.txt | grep BAR
BAR='eee'
```

However if I try this using `sed` it just prints everything

```
$ sed 's/;/\n/g; /BAR/!d' a.txt
FOO='hhh'
BAR='eee'
BAZ='ooo'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sh
$ sed 's/;/\n/g;/^BAR/!D;P;d' a.txt
BAR='eee'
```

- replace all `;` with `\n`
- delete until `BAR` line is at the top
- print `BAR` line
- delete pattern space

Answer (score 2):

With awk you could do this:

```
awk '/BAR/' RS=\; file
```

But if in the case of `BAZ` this would produce an extra newline, because the is no `;` after the last word. If you want to remove that newline as well you would need to do something like:

```
awk '/BAZ/{sub(/\n/,x); print}' RS=\;  file
```

or with GNU awk or mawk you could use:

```
awk '/BAZ/' RS='[;\n]'
```

---

If your grep has the -o option then you could also try this:

```
grep -o '[^;]*BAZ[^;]*' file
```

Answer (score 2):

`sed` can do it just as you want:

```
sed -n 's/.*\(BAR[^;]*\).*/\1/gp' <<< "FOO='hhh';BAR='eee';BAZ='ooo'"
```

The point here is that you must suppress `sed`'s default output -- the whole line --, and print only the substitutions you want to performed.

Noteworthy points:

- `sed -n` suppresses the default output;
- `s/.../.../g` operates in the entire line, even if already matched -- greedy;
- `s/.1./.2./p` prints out the substituted part (`.2.`);
- the `tr` part is given as the delimiter in the expression `\(BAR[^;]*\)`;
- the `grep` job is represented by the matching of the line itself.

Comment: One minore catch here might be that if one uses a partial match, for example `sed -n 's/.*\(AR[^;]*\).*/\1/gp' ` then this would produce `AR='eee'` instead of `BAR='eee'` .

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS=";"} /BAR/' a.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The following grep solution might work for you:

```
grep -o 'BAR=[^;]*' a.txt
```